# sending url query params in angular 4 doesn't work

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I have to pass query params to a post request in angular4 so i used HttpParams from angular 4 . This works fine with other post request but fails while accessing the authentication token from the backend.
This is how the query params should look like

```
grant_type=password&username=username&password=password
```

so i tried like this

```
login(username: string, password: string) {
    const headers = new HttpHeaders()
      .set('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded')
      .set('Accept', 'application/json');
      let params = new HttpParams();
      params = params.set('username', username);
      params = params.set('password', password);
      params = params.set('grant_type', 'password');
    return this.http.post('////////////', {params: params},
      { headers: headers }).subscribe(data => {
      console.log(data);
    },
    err => {
      console.log('Error occured');
    });
  }
```

Comment: please don't send passwords in a query string. They are logged in countless insecure locations between the browser and the server.

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: when you send an http request, the url, including the query string, is logged in several locations between the browser and the server, and most servers log their requests too.  These logs are not secure, and shouldn't contain plain text usernames and passwords.  This is why they're sent in the post body, which is never logged.

Comment: @bryan60 the OP is not passing the params in the query string. The params are sent, as JSON, in the request body.

Comment: the title reads "sending url query params in angular 4 doesn't work" and the code supports that this is what they're trying to accomplish, which is why I'm trying to advise against doing this, if I'm misreading, then my bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're passing your parameters as part of a JSON object containing a single key named `params`, whose value is the query string that should be the body itself.

It should be

```
return this.http.post(url, params.toString(), { headers })
```

Everything would be easier if your backend accepted JSON rather than x-www-form-urlencoded.

Comment: ok. so if i understand correctly. if the backend accepts x-www-form-urlencoded then i have to use params.toString(). right???

Comment: If it's x-www-form-urlencoded, you need to send, in the body of the request, a string that is in the x-www-form-urlencoded format.

Comment: May be you could answer my new question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47457879/sending-post-request-to-get-jwt-token-fails-work-after-adding-interceptor-for-an